# Calculation on gradient of the dot product on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ denote the standard dot product of vectors on $\mathbb{R^n}$. I'd like to confirm the formula that I have for the gradient of the dot product is correct. First, I consider this to be a map from $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ rather than one from $\mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. By this I mean:
$$
f(x,y) = f(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_iy_i
$$
Taking partial derivatives with respect to the $2n$ variables, we have that:
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = (y_1,...,y_n,x_1,...,x_n) = (y,x)
$$
Is this solution correct? I have not seen anything like this online.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\nabla(a\cdot x)=a$, which is well known. But it is an interesting perspective; it looks like $(\nabla\!\circ\cdot)$ is a reflection between the first $\mathbb R^n$ and the second $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: In fact, I'm studying a way to represent metric tensors (generalizations of the dot product) exactly as reflections between a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$, using $V\oplus V^*\cong\mathbb R^{n,n}$, a pseudo-Euclidean space. But it doesn't involve the gradient.